# SCIP/OR-Tools: Stop solver after certain objective value has been reached

Tags: linear-programming, or-tools, scip

I am using `or-tools` with a `SCIP` to solve some Mixed Integer Linear Program. In other solvers, I know there are options to stop the solver once a certain objective value has been reached, for example the `BestObjStop` option in GUROBI. Is there a similar option in `SCIP` as well? If so, is this option accessible via `or-tools` in `C++`?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no function implemented that directly does this in SCIP. There is a workaround that should work though.

You can set the objective limit (function `SCIPsetObjlimit`) to only accept solutions that are better than the objective stop you want. Then you set SCIP to stop as soon as you found a solution (parameter `limits/bestsol` set to 1).

I am not an or-tools user, so I am not sure how this should best be achieved in or-tools. This [recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72329251/how-seed-the-scip-solver-of-google-or-tools/72331798?noredirect=1#comment127794108_72331798) has an answer that tells you how to set specific SCIP parameters from or-tools. Looking at the code on github, it at least seems to me that you can set the objective limit when you call the Solve method with the right `GScipParameters`. Maybe an or-tools expert can improve this answer.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is: I want to abort the search not on when a certain objective value is reached, but when a certain constraint on the solution is constraint -- however, modelling that constraint directly in SCIP significantly slows down the search, which is why I would rather as a custom stop function.