# How seed the SCIP solver of google or-tools?

Tags: or-tools, seed, scip

As far as I know, other solvers which are available in or-tools can set specific random seed, but i couldn't find the way for scip solver.

How can I seed the SCIP solver?

Comment: Did you try to follow [this](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1609) and [this](https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/PARAMETERS.php)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with or-tools. But the random seed in SCIP is an integer parameter. So any way you would change another parameter is how you change the random seed. To me it seems there is a `setParams` function in or-tools that should do the trick.

Comment: You will need to use the text format of SCIP parameters, and `solver.SetSolverSpecificParametersAsString()`

Comment: @LaurentPerron could you explan how to set 'PRESOLVE_OFF' parameter?